# IntelliJ Typescript NoSuchElementException

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

I am getting this error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty` on IntelliJ Ultimate edition.

I suspected it to be linked with Typescript.

Any IDEA ? ^^

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:214)
    at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:197)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.frameworks.jsx.ReactClientComponentHighlightingStrategy.highlightCustomTag(ReactClientComponentHighlightingStrategy.kt:44)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.getCustomAttributeKey(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:115)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.replaceTextAttributeKeys(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:87)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.applyHighlighting(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:78)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.access$applyHighlighting(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:40)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass$doCollectInformation$1.visitXmlTag(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.xml.XmlTagImpl.accept(XmlTagImpl.java:268)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.e4x.impl.JSXmlLiteralExpressionImpl.accept(JSXmlLiteralExpressionImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:53)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.visit(PsiWalkingState.java:10)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.walkChildren(WalkingState.java:65)
    at com.intellij.util.WalkingState.elementStarted(WalkingState.java:42)
    at com.intellij.psi.PsiWalkingState.elementStarted(PsiWalkingState.java:62)
    at com.intellij.psi.XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.visitElement(XmlRecursiveElementWalkingVisitor.java:40)
    at com.intellij.lang.javascript.psi.impl.JSVarStatementBase.accept(JSVarStatementBase.java:49)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.SharedImplUtil.acceptChildren(SharedImplUtil.java:183)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PsiFileImpl.acceptChildren(PsiFileImpl.java:748)
    at com.intellij.xml.XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.doCollectInformation(XmlCustomTagHighlightingPass.kt:46)
    at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:55)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$1(PassExecutorService.java:406)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceKt.runWithSpanIgnoreThrows(trace.kt:76)
    at com.intellij.platform.diagnostic.telemetry.helpers.TraceUtil.runWithSpanThrows(TraceUtil.java:34)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$2(PassExecutorService.java:401)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1075)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$doRun$3(PassExecutorService.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:610)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:685)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:641)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:609)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:78)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.doRun(PassExecutorService.java:391)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.lambda$run$0(PassExecutorService.java:367)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:184)
    at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:365)
    at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
```